# .NET MAUI Android button pressed effect

Tags: c#, android, button, maui, maui-android

Is there a way to change the pressed effect of a button on Android in a .NET MAUI project. Now it is showing a dark ripple effect when dark mode is on and a white ripple effect when the light mode is on.
I would like to have the same ripple color for both dark and light mode. I tried to change the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark values but nothing changes.

Comment: I have created a new project to test the button on the android. The button showed the same ripple effect in the dark and light mode in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve parity in both modes (and potentially across platforms) might be to override the button's default style with your own.

You can look into the default [button style template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#button-controltemplate-example), make a copy in you apps resources, and change the colors used to from default staticresource or dynamicresource to your desired color palette.

Comment: Those use storyboards which I do not think are supported in .NET MAUI.